# VBA automation on IE tabs

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, tabs

I want to automate procedures on IE.

My macro works when opened on **windows**.

When I tried to run the same macro on **tabs** it didn't work.
It seems the macro isn't recognizing the tab.

```vb
Dim ie As Object
Dim dic As HTMLDocument
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
ie.Visible = True
On Error Resume Next
ie.navigate "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/ConsultaPublicaAreasEmbargadas.php"
           
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop        
Set doc = ie.document    
'IE.document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = "1234"
On Error Resume Next
doc.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = Sheets("Main").Range("C10")
doc.getElementById("Emitir_Certificado").Click
                            
' *until here works fine*                 
                                                                          
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.cnj.jus.br/improbidade_adm/consultar_requerido.php?validar=form", CLng(2048)
                            
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
                                
Set doc = ie.document

' *this line doesn't work, the tab opens but nothing happens*  
document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = Sheets("Main").Range("C10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to test your code on my side and found that after you open the second tab, your IE object still referring the first tab and inserting the value in it.

I try to modify your code added some code in it to find and move to the second tab and insert the value in that tab.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    IE.Visible = True


    URL = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/ConsultaPublicaAreasEmbargadas.php"


    IE.Navigate2 URL

    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until


    IE.document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = "demo" 'Sheets("Main").Range("C10")
    IE.document.getElementById("Emitir_Certificado").Click


    IE.Navigate2 "http://www.cnj.jus.br/improbidade_adm/consultar_requerido.php?validar=form", 2048&


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Set IE = GetIE("http://www.cnj.jus.br/improbidade_adm/consultar_requerido.php?validar=form")


    IE.document.getElementById("num_cpf_cnpj").Value = "demo1"
    'Unload IE
   ' Set IE = Nothing
   ' Set objElement = Nothing
   ' Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub


Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next  'because may not have a "document" property
        'Check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        ' assign the window object to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your requirement.

Comment: Buddy, I can't thank you enough! It worked perfectly! I even could add more tabs and the codes are working! May god bless you!! I tried to give you a vote but this message appeared "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". If there is anything I can do to help you, please let me know. And again, THANK YOU, you saved me!

Comment: Hi again, buddy. I add more tabs and I noticed that, sometimes, specially when the website is taking more time to open, the code "jump" that tab to the next (I add On Error Resume Next, before that, it was an 424 error) without add the numbers. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks again!

Comment: Try to wait for some more seconds and check whether it helps or not. For that you need to modify the value in this line. Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
 Try to wait for more then loading time of the page. Also I suggest you to wait before opening every new tab.

Comment: Hi, buddy! I'm sorry to take too long to answer, I had a rough weekend. I tried different delays, as you said, but even so, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. Do you have any other idea about how to solve this issue? I don't know very well about the rules here, but may I post the full code, by clicking on "Answer Your Question", sou you can see the full code? Thanks and have a great week!

Comment: You can try to edit your original post and post your full code or you can try to create a new thread with your full code as this thread is already answered. Please make sure that you remove all the confidential information in your code and replace it with dummy values. If you edit the original post then please try to inform us via posting the comment. We will try to check it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi, buddy. Thank you so much for your attention again! I posted the full code and my other problems in other topic. It would be a tremendous help if you could take a look again. Have a great day! Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273161/vba-automation-macro-isnt-working-very-well-on-ie-tabs

Comment: I tried to provide suggestion on new thread. Please check it in new thread. Thanks for your understanding.